# Where have I made my mistake in this javascript code to force download?

Tags: javascript, download

I have the following function in javascript.

```
function downloadFile(data, name = 'transcript.pdf', type = 'pdf') {
  const anchor = document.createElement('a')
  anchor.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], { type }))
  anchor.download = name
  anchor.click()
}

downloadFile();
```

Long story short, I am using a Learning management system. I cannot insert html, only javascript. So i Have a button press that executes the function above. I get the download window I want, the file looks right, its the right size, but when I go to open it, I get an unsupported file type/ corrupted file from adobe acrobat.

I know next to nothing about JS. I'm floundering around. Can anyone see the mistake I made and know how to correct it?

Comment: What is the value of `data`? Have you confirmed it is a PDF?

Comment: For the type is "application/pdf" not "pdf"